# SQL Rank and SUM

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am facing a bit of issue with an SQL query:

Currently I have 2 tables. The first table lists sales by a vendor and country eg and there are a lot more rows but this is just the gist.

```
Country id     Sale
US      1      100
UK      2      1000
US      3      150 
UK      2      200
```

In the second table I have ids that links to the vendor's name eg

```
id name
1  john
2  david 
3  tom
```

I need to get the top vendor in each country but sum of sales. the output should look something like this 
country id name sum_sales

Would you be able to help. Currently I am only able to groupby and sum and am unable to obtain the top guy in each country. thank you!

I am running this on big_query sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` with aggregation :

```
select yr, Country, id, name, total_sales
from (select extract(year from s.date) as yr,
             s.Country, s.id, v.name, sum(s.sales) as total_sales,
             dense_rank() over (partition by s.date, s.country order by sum(s.sales) desc) as seq
      from sales s inner join
           vendors v
           on v.id = v.id
      group by s.date, s.Country, s.id, v.name
     ) t
where seq <= 2;
```

EDIT : For specific year format use `FORMAT_DATETIME`

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y", DATETIME "2020-03-19")
```

By this way, you will get vendors for each country which are having higher sales.

Note : This will display two or more vendors which are having same total sales. If you want only one from them, then use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`.

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . Add `year` in `group by` & `partition` clause with `seq <= 2` then.

Comment: thank you this helps. 

I hope its ok that i ask a follow up question. In the same table i also have a list of dates and am trying to find the top 2 vendors by sales in each country in each year. i have added extract(year from date ) as year and replaced seq to <=2 but i am not getting what i need.would you be able to help? thanks!

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . You should ask other question with sample data would help you.

Comment: Sample data is 
country  date             id sale 
UK         15/12/2010  1  100
US          12/1/2011    2   200

vendors table is same as earlier

Comment: code used is: 

select Country, id, name, total_sales
from (select s.Country, s.id, v.name, sum(s.sales) as total_sales, extract(year from date) as year,
             dense_rank() over (partition by s.country order by year, sum(s.sales) desc) as seq
      from sales s inner join
           vendors v
           on v.id = v.id
      group by s.Country, s.id, v.name, year
     ) t
where seq <=2;

error:unrecognized name year at 3

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . . I made changes.

Comment: when i add in the extract (year from date) after partition by, i get an error-> partition by references column date whihc is niiether grouped nor aggregated

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . I think you need a date. Check further edited.

Comment: thanks. sorry can i trouble you with one final question - when i change it to year i get the year (as expected). id like ot format it as say 2010-01-01 00:00:00 so basically every year will have the same date time. for a different year say 2009 it will be 2009-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . .  Hint `Year()`.

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . However, you can change to `extract(year from s.date)` to `year(date)` to make it general.

Comment: yep i had tried year but i got a function not found error :(

Comment: yes i did, resulted in an error unable to convert int 64 to datetime unfort

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty. . . I am not very familiar with GBigQuery. So, i would ask for `FORMAT_DATETIME` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you can use window functions with aggregation:

```
select id, name, country, sum_sales
from (select s.id, v.name, s.country, sum(sales) as sum_sales
             row_number() over (partition by s.country order by sum(sales) desc) as seqnum
      from sales s join
           vendors v
           on v.id = v.id
      group by s.id, v.name, s.country
     ) sv
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon thank you, however I am getting this error - SELECT list expression references v.name which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:15]

Would you be able to help with this please?

Comment: @NatashaLakhpaty . . . Oops, all those columns should be in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY sum_sale DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM (
  SELECT country, id, name, SUM(sale) sum_sale
  FROM `project.dataset.vendors`
  JOIN `project.dataset.sales`
  USING(id)
  GROUP BY id, name, country
) t
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: did you have chance to try?